# How to pass a private variable as the default optional parameter in C#

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

In the provided example, the function declaration `PrintBar` is throwing an error because `_bar` is not a compile time constant. What is the best practice to avoid this issue?

```
using System;

class Foo
{
    private readonly string _bar;
    public Foo(string initBar)
    {
        _bar = initBar;
    }

    public void PrintBar(string value = _bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `null` be the default? And replace it with `_bar` if `null` was passed.

Comment: If you want the non-constant value of `_bar` to be used as default I'd use `null` as formal default: `void PrintBar(string value = null)`
and in the method's body replace null by `_bar`.

Comment: I question the sense in a method called "PrintBar" that might possibly *not* print `_bar`. Instead of overloading, give them different names entirely. I recognize that this might be a trivial example, but the same line of reasoning should be used to inform your design decisions in real-world scenarios, as well.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest *overloading* esp. in case *Dmitry's* solution (using `null` as default and then assign `_bar` if `null` passed) is not a way out (when `null` can well be passed as a *valid input*):

```
public void PrintBar(string value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

public void PrintBar() => PrintBar(_bar);
```